# failed to run python script from laravel using symfony process (Exit Code: -1073740791(Unknown error) )

Tags: php, python, laravel, symfony

i am trying to run python script from laravel using symfony process. 
here is my controller

```
public function test()
{
    $process = new Process("C:/Users/faraz/Anaconda3/python C:/xampp/htdocs/fyp_final1/public/temp.py");
    $process->run();

    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    dump(json_decode($process->getOutput(), true));

}
```

here is my python script, i placed it in public folder of my project.

```
import json
data='abc'
print(json.dumps(data))
```

**Error**

> The command "C:/Users/faraz/Anaconda3/python C:/xampp/htdocs/fyp_final1/public/temp.py" failed. Exit Code: -1073740791(Unknown error) Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp_final1\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python

how ever when i run it on terminal it works fine.

Comment: Possibly it is a file system error.

Comment: @Mohammad Faraz Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: Do you find any solution?